# read only the first and last row of several file at once with R

Tags: r, dplyr, row, plyr, read.table

I got many .csv files of different sizes. I choose some of them who correspond at a condition (those matching with my `id` in the example). They are ordered by date and can be huge. I need to know the minimum and maximum dates of these files.

I can read all of those wanted and only for the column `date.hour`, and then I can find easily the minimum and maximum of all the dates values.

But it would be a lot faster, as I repeat this for thousand ids, if I could read only the first and last rows of my files.

Does anyone got an idea of how to solve this ?

This code works well, but I wish to improve it.

## function to read several files at once

```
`read.tables.simple <- function(file.names, ...) {require(plyr)
ldply(file.names, function(fn) data.frame(read.table(fn, ...)))}`
```

## reading the files and selecting the minimum and maximum dates for all of theses

```
`diri <- dir()
dat <- read.tables.simple(diri[1], header = TRUE, sep = ";", colClasses = "character")
colclass <- rep("NULL", ncol(dat))
x <- which(colnames(dat) == "date.hour")
colclass[x] <- "character"
x <- grep("id", diri)
dat <- read.tables.simple(diri[x], header = TRUE, sep = ";", colClasses = colclass)
datmin <- min(dat$date.hour)
datmax <- max(dat$date.hour)`
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function will read the first two lines of your csv (the header row and the first data row), then `seek` to the end of the file and read the last line. It will then stick these three lines together to read them as a two-row csv in memory from which it returns the column `date.time`. This will have your minimum and maximum values, since the times are arranged in order.

You need to tell the function the maximum line length. It's OK if you over-estimate this, but make sure the number is less than a third of your file size.

```
read_head_tail <- function(file_path, line_length = 100)
{
  con <- file(file_path)
  open(con)
  seek(con, where = 0)
  first <- suppressWarnings(readChar(con, nchars = 2 * line_length))
  first <- strsplit(first, "\n")[[1]][1:2]
  seek(con, where = file.info(file_path)$size - line_length)
  last <- suppressWarnings(readChar(con, nchars = line_length))
  last <- strsplit(last, "\n")[[1]]
  last <- last[length(last)]
  close(con)
  csv <- paste(paste0(first, collapse = "\n"), last, sep = "\n")
  df <- read.csv(text = csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[-1]
  return(df$date.hour)
}
```

Comment: Your function looks useful, but unfortunately will not work in my case. I have to read several files following an id, at once, and I do not know the size of the files. They are ordered by date (normally), but the sizes are between couples Ko to Go.

Comment: @VPMancy you don't need to know the length of the files. To get all the results in a directory you could just do for example `lapply(diri[x], read_head_tail, 300)`

Answer (score 0):

In general, `read.table` is very slow. If you use `read_tsv`, `read_csv` or `read_delim` from the `readr` library, it will already be much, much faster.

If you are on Linux/Mac OS, you can also read only the first or last parts by setting up a pipe, which will be more or less instant, no matter how large your file is. Let's assume you have no column headers:

```r
library(readr)
read_last <- function(file) {
  read_tsv(pipe(paste('tail -n 1', file)), col_names=FALSE)
}

# Readr can already read only a select number of lines, use `n_max`
first <- read_tsv(file, n_max=1, col_names=FALSE)
```

If you want to go in on parallelism, you can even read files in parallel, see e.g., `library(parallel)` and `?mclapply`

Comment: Hi, in my case, read.table is more appropriate I think because it is the easiest function to use while you want to only read one variable. This is why I use this one, in this case. I am not on unix/mac now, but will change for it this year. So I will keep your comment in mind.

Comment: Hi, see the `col_types` argument for `readr::read_csv` and the `cols_only()` function of readr.  They do exactly what you refer to. As for `tail`, you could always install GNU core utilities in Windows through Cygwin. See https://www.cygwin.com/ and https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fcoreutils%2Fcoreutils-8.26-2&grep=core